# Python: how to groupby a given percentile?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataframe `df`

```
df
    User   City     Job             Age
0    A      x    Unemployed         33
1    B      x     Student           18
2    C      x    Unemployed         27
3    D      y  Data Scientist       28
4    E      y    Unemployed         45
5    F      y     Student           18
```

I want to `groupby` the `City` and do some stat. If I have to compute the mean, I can do the following:

```
tmp = df.groupby(['City']).mean()
```

I would like to do same by a specific quantile. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrameGroupBy.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.quantile.html):

```
tmp = df.groupby('City')['Age'].quantile(0.4)
print (tmp)
City
x    25.2
y    26.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

---

```
tmp = df.groupby('City')['Age'].quantile([0.25, 0.75]).unstack().add_prefix('q')
print (tmp)
      q0.25  q0.75
City              
x      22.5   30.0
y      23.0   36.5
```

Answer (score 4):

```
def q1(x):
    return x.quantile(0.25)

def q2(x):
    return x.quantile(0.75)

fc = {'Age': [q1,q2]}
temp = df.groupby('City').agg(fc)
temp

       Age      
        q1    q2
City            
x     22.5  30.0
y     23.0  36.5
```

Comment: Please post the output as well

Comment: Apologies, I've added the output as well. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am using `describe`

```
df.groupby('City')['Age'].describe()[['25%','75%']]
Out[542]: 
       25%   75%
City            
x     22.5  30.0
y     23.0  36.5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df.groupby('City')['Age'].apply(lambda x: np.percentile(x,[25,75])).reset_index().rename(columns={'Age':'25%, 75%'})

  City      25%, 75%
0    x  [22.5, 30.0]
1    y  [23.0, 36.5]
```